# Any online site with limited number of games per day like chess.com or chess24

Tags: online-chess

I have a problem that when I start to play I cannot stop, and I am looking for some good online chess web site that have limited number of rated games per day for, lets say non premium user, or something like that. Like thay have for tactis.

Comment: I dont think there is one. They either let you play all the games you want, or none at all. Only other types of features come in that flavor of X per day

Comment: I am not aware of any either, but I believe there is software that limits computer use in general. Through a search I found something called "StayFocused" which seems to allow you to limit time spent on certain websites. Other products might exist.

Comment: @user1583209 Good idea with StayFocused, I wasn't aware that such thing exists, I will try it. Thanks :).

Answer (score 2):

I have heard others make the same complaint and a friend decided to use the Makua software which will limit your computer time.  There is probably other software that does the same, mostly for parents to limit their kids but you can use it on yourself.

Comment: I installed StayFocused and limited amount of time that I spend on chess.com successfully, but still, if I limit a time on for example 45 minutes, I am still able to play number of short clueless games that will ruin my rating :))))